# ricci tensor of 2-sphere $S^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

Hi could someone show me explicitly how to compute the ricci tensor $g_{ij}$?
[image]

Comment: Do you have/know the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor#Coordinate_expression) for the curvature components in terms of the [Christoffel symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols)? From there it should be just a lengthy computational slog. Or are you willing to use the known fact that the round metric is Einstein...?

Comment: I really don't know much Riemannian geomrty. Though I did feel the direction you suggested, I simply know too little to write them down, could you help? Once I see an explicit example, should be able go to a textbook to read/learn in detail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might not be the most straightforward way, but it's a nice trick that bypasses a lot of the calculation. For the Ricci tensor we use [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Ricci_and_scalar_curvatures):
$$R_{ij}=\frac{\partial { \Gamma^l}_{ij}}{\partial x^l}-\frac{\partial { \Gamma^l}_{il}}{\partial x^j}+{ \Gamma^l}_{ij}{ \Gamma^m}_{lm}-{ \Gamma^m}_{il}{ \Gamma^l}_{jm}$$

Where we sum over repeated indices, and instead of lets say ${ \Gamma^1}_{21}$ I will write explicitly ${ \Gamma^\theta}_{\phi\theta}$.

We could just use a formula and calculate everything directly, but here's a faster approach. It's known that geodesics extremize arclength. That is, given a curve $\gamma:[0,1]\to M$, with its tangent (or velocity) vector $T^a (t_0) =\gamma_*( \frac{\partial}{\partial t}|_{t=t_0})\in T_{\gamma(t_0)}M$ and given the functional 
 $$ S[\gamma ]:=\int_{t=0}^{t=1} \left( g_{ab} T^a T^b \right)^{1/2}\mathrm d t$$
called arc-length, $\gamma$ is a geodesic iff it extremizes $S$.

Let's call the integrand $\left( g_{ab} T^a T^b \right)^{1/2}=(2L)^{1/2}$. It can be shown explicitly that the resulting equations are the same as if we had the integrand (in coordinates) $$L=\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}\frac{d x^{\mu}}{d t}\frac{d x^{\nu}}{d t}$$

which isn't strange since one integrand is a monotonic function of the other.

So if we compare the Euler-Lagrange equation with the geodesic equation, $$\begin{align}\text{Euler-Lagrange: }\: \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x^i}&=\frac{\partial L}{\partial x^i}\\
\text{Geodesic:} \phantom{{}=1}\frac{d^2 x^{i}}{d t^2}&= -{ \Gamma^i}_{jk}\frac{d x^{j}}{d t}\frac{d x^{k}}{d t}\end{align}$$

we see that if we find the E-L equations, we find the Christoffel symbols, and the Ricci tensor. 
In our case

$$L=\frac{1}{2}\left(\dot \theta^2 + \sin^2\theta\:\dot\phi^2\right)$$

where the dots indicate derivatives wrt the parameter $t$. 
For the $\theta$ coordinate we find: 
$$\ddot\theta=\sin\theta\cos\theta\:\dot\phi^2$$
and we conclude that 
$${\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\phi\phi}=-\sin\theta\cos\theta,\:{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\theta\phi}={\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\phi\theta}={\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\theta\theta}=0$$

Similarly, the other equation is $\frac{d}{dt}(\sin\theta\:\dot\phi):$
$$\ddot\phi = -\cot\theta\:\dot\theta\dot\phi$$
so that
$${\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\theta\phi}={\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\phi\theta}=\cot\theta,\:{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\theta\theta}={\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\phi\phi}=0.$$

So we calculate the Ricci tensor components:

$$R_{\phi\phi}=\partial_{\phi}{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\phi\phi}+\partial_{\theta}{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\phi\phi}-\partial_{\phi}{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\phi\phi}-\partial_{\phi}{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\theta\phi} + 
{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\phi\phi}{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\phi\phi}
+
{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\phi\phi}{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\phi\theta}
+
{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\phi\phi}{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\theta\phi}
+
{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\phi\phi}{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\theta\theta}
- 
{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\phi\phi}{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\phi\phi}
-
{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\phi\theta}{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\phi\phi}
- 
{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\phi\phi}{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\phi\theta}
-
{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\phi\theta}{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\phi\theta}
= 0 +(\sin^2\theta- \cos^2\theta) - 0 - 0 +0 +0 +(-\sin\theta\cos\theta\cot\theta)+0-0-(-\sin\theta\cos\theta\cot\theta)-(-\sin\theta\cos\theta\cot\theta)-0 = \sin^2\theta $$

$$R_{\phi\theta}=R_{\theta\phi}=\partial_{\phi}{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\phi\theta}+\partial_{\theta}{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\phi\theta}-\partial_{\theta}{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\phi\phi}-\partial_{\theta}{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\phi\phi} + 
{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\phi\theta}{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\phi\phi}
+
{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\phi\theta}{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\phi\theta}
+
{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\phi\theta}{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\theta\phi}
+
{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\phi\theta}{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\theta\theta}
- 
{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\phi\phi}{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\theta\phi}
-
{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\phi\theta}{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\theta\phi}
- 
{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\phi\phi}{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\theta\theta}
-
{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\phi\theta}{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\theta\theta} = 0 + 0 - 0 - 0 + 0 + 0 +0 +0 -0 -0 -0 -0 = 0 $$

$$R_{\theta\theta}=\partial_{\phi}{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\theta\theta}+\partial_{\theta}{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\theta\theta}-\partial_{\theta}{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\theta\phi}-\partial_{\theta}{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\theta\theta} + 
{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\theta\theta}{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\phi\phi}
+
{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\theta\theta}{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\phi\theta}
+
{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\theta\theta}{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\theta\phi}
+
{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\theta\theta}{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\theta\theta}
- 
{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\theta\phi}{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\theta\phi}
-
{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\theta\theta}{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\theta\phi}
- 
{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\theta\phi}{\Gamma^{\phi}}_{\theta\theta}
-
{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\theta\theta}{\Gamma^{\theta}}_{\theta\theta}= 0 + 0 - (- \csc^2\theta)- 0+0+0+0+0-\cot^2\theta-0-0-0 = 1$$

To get the scalar curvature, we form

$$R = g^{ij}R_{ij} = g^{\phi\phi}R_{\phi\phi}+g^{\theta\theta}R_{\theta\theta}= \csc^2{\theta}\sin^2\theta + 1=2.$$

Comment: @kryvolok: will be looking into it...Could that be a more straightforward way to get $g_{ij}$?

Comment: The other way to get the symbols is just plugging the metric into the formula but that is extremely tedious.... about as much work as getting one of the Ricci components, for just one symbol!