# How can I exploit this definition to proof that spherical surfaces aren't flat?

Tags: surfaces, curvature

I read in a book that a space is flat if it is possible write infinitesimal displacement (squared) as $ds^2=\xi_1 (du^1)^2+\cdots+\xi_n (du^n)^2$ where $\xi_i = \pm 1$: it is flat if it exists a coordinate system that do that. In another book a read that cylindrical surfaces are flat while spherical ones are not. Where is the link between these two claims? I tried starting by (here $R$ is fixed)
$$
ds^2 = R^2 \, d\phi^2 + dz^2 \qquad \textrm{Cylindrical case}
$$
$$
ds^2 = R^2 \, d \theta^2 + R^2 \sin^2 \theta \, d \phi^2 \qquad \textrm{Spherical case}
$$
and then noting that choosing $u^1 = R \phi$ and $u^2 = z$ we get $ds^2 = (du^1)^2+(du^2)^2$. *Apparently* it is impossible do the same in spherical case. But how can I prove that I can't find $u^1 = u^1 (\theta,\phi)$ and $u^2 = u^2 (\theta,\phi)$ such that $R^2 d \theta^2 + R^2 \sin^2 \theta \, d \phi^2 = (du^1)^2+(du^2)^2 $? It look like I should prove that doesn't exist $u^1 = u^1 (\theta,\phi)$ and $u^2 = u^2 (\theta,\phi)$ such that
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l} \displaystyle 
\left( \frac{ \partial u^1 }{ \partial \theta } \right)^2 + 
\left( \frac{ \partial u^2 }{ \partial \theta } \right)^2 = R^2 \\ \displaystyle 
\left( \frac{ \partial u^1 }{ \partial \phi } \right)^2 + 
\left( \frac{ \partial u^2 }{ \partial \phi } \right)^2 = R^2 \sin^2 \theta \\ \displaystyle 
\frac{ \partial u^1 }{ \partial \theta } \frac{ \partial u^1 }{ \partial \phi } + 
\frac{ \partial u^2 }{ \partial \theta } \frac{ \partial u^2 }{ \partial \phi } = 0
\end{array} \right.
$$
But I have no idea of how to prove that (for some reason these three conditions are not compatible?) and so showing that starting definition of flat space can exploited to prove that cylindrical surface is flat (I did it!) while spherical it is not (I can't do it!).

Answer (score 1):

A good way to solve a problem like this is to compute a quantity that is defined in terms of the metric (i.e. in terms of $ds^2$) and is invariant under coordinate reparametrisations. If the value this quantity takes for the sphere metric is different from the value this quantity takes for a flat 2D metric, then that would prove that there is no coordinate reparametrisation that turns the sphere metric into the flat Euclidean metric.

The [Ricci scalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_curvature) is such a quantity. The Ricci scalar is defined in terms of the metric and is invariant under coordinate reparametrisations.

On a 2-sphere of unit radius, the Ricci scalar evaluates to $2$ everywhere (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394372/ricci-tensor-of-2-sphere-s2)). On flat 2D Euclidean space, the Ricci scalar evaluates to $0$ everywhere. So it is impossible for there to exist a coordinate reparametrisation that converts the metric of the 2-sphere into the metric of flat 2D Euclidean space.

Comment: So, again, I need the toolbox of tensor calculus. Trying to get it is really leading me to madness "all work and no understanding tensors makes me a dull boy". The subject is very difficult and each author uses his own notations, jump basis, and continues on his own. Every time I understand one thing I have to back off because I don't understand others.

Comment: I looked, without high hopes, for Einstein's words in "Relativity: The Special and the General Theory ", but I found it very very enlightening (see section 24). Despite spheres and cylinders are not cited, I understood why the definition at the beginning of my question is interesting and why it is linked with the fact that the cylindrical surface is flat while the spherical one it is not (try to cover a sphere of boxed x built with geodesics, it's impossible, while for a cylinder it is crearly doable) (Einstein speak about temperature of the plane but the same would be if the plane was curved)

Comment: Einstein there spoke about euclidean spaces not flat spaces. Interesting but not very pertinent to the question, they seem two different concepts: using Gauss minK*maxK definition it is easy to see that cone surface is flat. But Einstein reasoning suggests that cone surface is not euclidean. I wrong?

Comment: I read that Einstein book too when I was a child? If you're talking about the geodesic convergence property, it's lovely, isn't it? On your second question, the surface of the cone is flat, expect at the tip, where it has infinite curvature. Einstein must have been referring to the tip.

Comment: Einstein does not speak of cones. It's me who tried to apply his reasoning to the cone. His physical/operative method of seeing if a 2D space is Euclidean is charming. With tiny rods is he look if it is possible to create a web of square (he also operationally defines the meaning of this statement). Clearly it is possible for the cylinder and I can guess that it is not for the sphere. the cone is a slightly more delicate case but since it can be rolled out on a plane now I think it is analogous to the cylinder. But it is not clear to me If flat and euclidean they are synonyms.