# Operations related to second rank tensors and Ricci

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors

For covariant and contravariant second rank tensors we have:

$B_{jk} B^{jk}= B^{jk} B_{jk} = \text{invariant}$

For the second rank Ricci tensor we also have

$R_{jk} R^{jk}= R^{jk} R_{jk} = \text{invariant} \quad (1)$

The scalar curvature is defined as the trace of the Ricci curvature tensor with respect to the metric and is given by:

$R = g^{jk} R_{jk}$

Is the invariant obtained in $(1)$ the same as the scalar curvature $R$ or not?

Please explain or correct me if I'm wrong, I am in the process of learning tensor calculus.

Comment: What do you mean by "invariant"? The quantity in (1) can be seen as a certain kind of invariant, but I am not sure is this is relevant in this context.

Answer (score 1):

The scalar curvature $R$ and (1), which is the square of the Ricci tensor $|R|^2$, are different quantities: you may see this in coordinates at a point where $R$ will be some matrix, and $g$ will be in general some other matrix, so there is no need for these things to be equal.

If you are not convinced, try to calculate these quantities on a standardly embedded sphere $\mathbb{S}^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ with the induced metric and the intrinsic curvatures. You may find [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1394567/2002) helpful.

Comment: Thanks. Does the quatitiy in (1) or the square of the Ricci tensor perhaps have a formula in terms of the metric tensor or Christoffel symbols or something like that?

Comment: It does. One can start with the coordinate expression for the Ricci tensor (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature#Definition_via_local_coordinates_on_a_smooth_manifold)) and explicitly compute $R_{ij}R^{ij}$.